# Calculating area for polygons in arctic areas

Tags: coordinate-system, area, arctic

We are evaluating areas of ecological importance in the arctic. The asset areas are of different sizes (up to 10 square kilometres) from latitudes 64 to 80 degrees north. The areas also vary in longitude from -10 degrees to +40 degrees.

Since the areas calculation are important in the evaluation of the assets we need a conform method to calculate their areas. What would be the best approach? Which projection would be better?

Comment: Can you use PostGIS and geography data type https://postgis.net/docs/geography.html?

Comment: What size roughly are the assets themselves? Thousands, hundreds, or tens of km across?

Comment: These are sea bottom species - Caulophacus arcticus, Asconema setubalense and others. I am guessing up to 10 square kilometers as a maximum. For us it is important to know if it is a single observation or an area covered in categories 0, 0+ to 15, 15 to 25 or +25 km.

Comment: You could try using EPSG:6931 which uses Lambert azimuthal equal area. If you're building your polygons of interest in lat/lon, make sure to densify them before projecting them into any projected coordinate reference system.